# dockerfile postgresl create role

Tags: sql, bash, postgresql, docker, postgresql-10

PostgreSQL 10

I'm trying to create a role in a docker container on launch

I've tried creating the role like so:

```
gosu postgres pg_ctl start -D /var/lib/postgresql/data

if [ "${PGUSER}" != 'postgres' ]; then
  gosu postgres psql --command="CREATE USER ${PGUSER} SUPERUSER WITH PASSWORD '${PGPASSWORD}';" --echo-hidden --echo-queries
fi

gosu postgres pg_ctl stop -w -D /var/lib/postgresql/data
```

This still gives me *FATAL:  role "grafadmin" does not exist*

When attempting to create a database with:

```
gosu postgres createdb -O grafadmin grafana
```

I've also tried:

```
cat > ${HOMEDIR}/user.sql <<SQL
DO
$body$
BEGIN
   IF NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT
      FROM   pg_catalog.pg_user
      WHERE  username = '${PGUSER}') THEN
      CREATE ROLE ${PGUSER} WITH SUPERUSER PASSWORD '${PGPASSWORD}';
   END IF;
END
$body$;
SQL
cat ${HOMEDIR}/user.sql
gosu postgres psql --file="${HOMEDIR}/user.sql" --echo-hidden --echo-queries
```

I'm probably overlooking something simple ...

Answer (score 0):

Prefer `CREATE USER` instead of `CREATE ROLE` when you create user that can log in. It will add an extra parameter `LOGIN`. Without it you cannot login.

```
cat > ${HOMEDIR}/user.sql <<SQL
DO
$body$
BEGIN
   IF NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT
      FROM   pg_catalog.pg_user
      WHERE  username = '${PGUSER}') THEN
      CREATE USER ${PGUSER} WITH SUPERUSER PASSWORD '${PGPASSWORD}';
   END IF;
END
$body$;
SQL
cat ${HOMEDIR}/user.sql
gosu postgres psql --file="${HOMEDIR}/user.sql" --echo-hidden --echo-queries
```

for more see : https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-createuser.html